# Not able to run/compile AudioKit V4.3 in Xcode10

Tags: cocoapods, ios11, audiokit, xcode10, ios12

Is AudioKit v4.3 compatible with Xcode10.0.3, iOS12? I'm absolute newbie and running into errors after errors since a week and not able to make a basic oscillator hello world program.

After installing pod file for AudioKit with following info:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
  use_frameworks!

target 'sound' do

 pod 'AudioKit', '~> 4.3'

 # Pods for sound

 target 'soundTests' do
   inherit! :search_paths
   # Pods for testing
 end

 target 'soundUITests' do
   inherit! :search_paths
   # Pods for testing
 end

 end
```

-When I use toolchains Swift 4.1.2 - I get the error : "Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code."

-So I used Toolchains Xcode 10.0 and get the error : "Module compiled with Swift 4.1 cannot be imported in Swift 4.2"

-I've also tried keeping target device as macOS, Generic device, iOS 6-X and my phone as well.

-When I used AudioKit playground, oscillator did work when destination was set as macOS.

-I also tried adding "Embedded Binaries" (AudioKit and AudioKitUI frameworks) manually in General tab.

Please let me know where's it going wrong? I've searched all over and not able to fix this issue. Can't wait to build something as basic as Hello World oscillator.

**Edit:**

- I went back to Xcode 9.4.1 after advice from a dev.
- I'm also switched to Toolchain: Swift 4.0.2 Release 2017-11-01 (a) since I was still getting compile issues.
- But despite of it I get error : Module compiled with Swift 4.0.2 cannot be imported in Swift 4.1.2 (I'm literally running 4.0.2 Toolchain!)
- I tried <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to clean the entire project and build with Command + B. Still no changes.
- 2 other warnings that I'm continuously getting are:
- "No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression"
- 'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block

What did I do wrong to not deserve AudioKit!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use beta software like Xcode, you can't also use Cocoapods to install AudioKit.  You'll have to build it yourself with the `Frameworks/build_frameworks.sh` script.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply!
-I went back to XCode 9.4.1 which is a stable release (not beta). I'm able to install AudioKit with cocoapods.
-I switched to Toolchain: Swift 4.0.2 since I was getting compile issues.
-I get the error: Module compiled with Swift 4.0.2 cannot be imported in Swift 4.1.2 (I'm running 4.0.2 Toolchain)
-I tried Cmd+Shift+K to clean the project and built with Command + B. Still no changes.
-2 other warnings that I'm getting are :
"No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression"
'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block

Comment: Can you explain why it is not possible to use Cocoapods with Xcode Beta version?

Comment: AudioKit is prebuilt for Cocoapods, so the Swift versions do not match with the beta version of Xcode.